# setText on textview without replacing sketchware

Tags: sketchware

I need to edit the textview without replacing the all text, for example
myText : Hi
Like if i click the button it will add "Hello" , so it should be like this "Hi Hello" without replacing the all text.

Sorry for bad English.

I used setText and it replace all text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

This is your first text view

```
textview1.setText("hi");
```

And if your button clicked , add this code for change "hi" to "hi hello"

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _view){
        textview1.setText(textview1.getText().toString().concat(" hello"));
    }
});
```